# Get the last inserted ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the ID of the last row inserted into a table and use it with a variable in SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('profiles')
```

I tried adding a where clause

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('profiles') WHERE profiles.userid = '2'
```

Here is my error:

> The multi-part identifier "profiles.userid" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your 2nd Query

To make the second query with the `WHERE` clause work (*to the extent that it does not error*), you need to anchor the multi-part identifier `profiles.userid` with a `FROM`:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('profiles') FROM profiles WHERE profiles.userid = '2'
```

*But this does not make a lot of sense* because the `WHERE` clause will not really change the bottom-line result (i.e. the last identity generated for `profile`) - just possibly include it more than once in the result set.

### Back to Your 1st Query

If you really want to get the last identity value generated for `profile` to delete the row it identifies, then your first query...

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('profiles')
```

...is the direction to go.

Of course, you will then need to employ the last identity value generated for `profile` in a `DELETE` statement rather than just a `SELECT` - for example (assuming that the identity column in `profiles` is `id`)...

```
DECLARE @lastID int;
SELECT @lastID = IDENT_CURRENT('profiles');

DELETE FROM profiles WHERE id = @lastID;
```

..., which would really just be better said as:

```
DELETE FROM profiles WHERE id = IDENT_CURRENT('profiles');
```

Comment: @thisisME: We may have been writing at the same time, but this is what I am saying as of my last edit - that while adding the `FROM` clause will fix the error you are seeing, it does not make a lot of sense because `IDENT_CURRENT('profiles')`'s return value is going to be the same regardless of the `WHERE` clause.  The `WHERE` clause will only affect the number of times `IDENT_CURRENT('profiles')`'s return value is in the query's result set...since the result set will include its return value as many times as the `WHERE` clause matches.

Comment: thank you @j0e3gan, can I use this code? `SELECT top 1 IDENT_CURRENT('shopfloors') from shopfloors where userid = '2'` do you think this is fine ? thank you

Comment: @thisisME: It will work, but it is just a convoluted way of saying `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('shopfloors')`.

Comment: thank you may be i will use `SELECT top 1 IDENT_CURRENT('shopfloors') from shopfloors where userid = '2'`